# Reconciling regex behaviors

Tags: regex, r

I am trying a regex (`(?:I\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\d)*`) [here](https://regex101.com/r/bJ3iA3/4#pcre):

Out of the string `A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F-I1-I3-D-D-D-D-I1-I1-I3-I1-I1-I3-I2-L-K-I3-P-F-I2-I2` I get the following matches `I1-I3`, `I1-I1-I3-I1-I1-I3-I2`, and `I3` - this is the desired behavior. However, in R:

```
x <- "A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F-I1-I3-D-D-D-D-I1-I1-I3-I1-I1-I3-I2-L-K-I3-P-F-I2-I2"
strsplit(x, "(?:I\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\d)*")
```

this returns an error:

```
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:I\d"
```

I have tried `perl=TRUE`, but it doesn't make a difference.

I have also tried to modify the regex to read: `(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*`, however this does not give the correct result, rather it matches `A-B-C-I1-I2-D-E-F-`, `-D-D-D-D-`, `-L-K-`, and `-P-F-I2-I2`.
`
How can I replicate the desired behavior in R?

Comment: Try with `\\d` as you need to escape . i.e. `strsplit(x, "(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*")`

Comment: @akrun: this does not give the desired result - see updated question.

Comment: I didn't check the desired result as I was trying to fix the error.

Comment: @akrun: the question is: "How can I replicate the desired behavior in R?"

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, '(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*')`  I said that I only looked at the error part.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to `split` the string and get the substring based on the pattern showed, we may be use that as the pattern to be skipped (`(*SKIP)(*F)`) and split the string with the rest of the characters.

```
 v1 <- strsplit(x, '(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*(*SKIP)(*F)|.', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
```

The blank/empty elements can be removed using `nzchar` to return a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE depending on whether there the string is not blank or is blank.

```
 v1[nzchar(v1)]
 #[1] "I1-I3"                "I1-I1-I3-I1-I1-I3-I2" "I3"
```

Or as we are interested more in extracting the pattern, `str_extract` would be useful.

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract_all(x, '(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*')[[1]]
 #[1] "I1-I3"                "I1-I1-I3-I1-I1-I3-I2" "I3"
```